# Select max(sort_key) from tbl_5billion_rows taking too long

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have redshift table with 5 billion rows which is going to grow alot in near future. When I run a simple query
 `select max(sort_key) from tbl` 
 it takes 30 sec. 
I have only one sort key in the table.
I have run vacuum and analyze on the table recently.
 The reason I am worried about 30 sec is, I use max(sort_key) multiple times in my subquery.
 Is there anything I am missing?

**Output** Explain select max(sort_key) from tbl

```
XN Aggregate  (cost=55516326.40..55516326.40 rows=1 width=4)
  ->  XN Seq Scan on tbl  (cost=0.00..44413061.12 rows=4441306112 width=4)
```

**Output** Explain select sort_key from tbl order by sortkey desc limit 1

```
XN Limit  (cost=1000756095433.11..1000756095433.11 rows=1 width=4)
->  XN Merge  (cost=1000756095433.11..1000767198698.39 rows=4441306112 width=4)
        Merge Key: sort_key
        ->  XN Network  (cost=1000756095433.11..1000767198698.39 rows=4441306112 width=4)
              Send to leader
              ->  XN Sort  (cost=1000756095433.11..1000767198698.39 rows=4441306112 width=4)
                    Sort Key: sort_key
                    ->  XN Seq Scan on tbl  (cost=0.00..44413061.12 rows=4441306112 width=4)
```

Comment: Are there many rows (sort_keys) with the same value?

Comment: @kometen probably 1000 for each value of sort key.

Comment: An alternative query is "select sort_key order by sort_key desc limit 1;". It may not run faster. Can you add the output of "explain analyze select max(sort_key) from tbl;" to your question?

Comment: Have you made changes to postgresql.conf? If not you can look at https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server as a starting point, especially shared_buffers, effective_cache_size and maybe work_mem. Is the db in production or can you test various settings? They require a restart of the db (not server).

Comment: @kometen - No, I havent changed anything in conf file. Is it the same file for Redshift? It is in production, and I am not sure how to restart just the db and not the cluster.

Comment: @RedshiftGuy, do you have an index over sort_key field?

Comment: @icuken - Redshift does not support index.

Comment: @RedshiftGuy, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

Finding the `MAX()` of a value requires Amazon Redshift to look through every value in the column. It probably isn't smart enough to realise that the `MAX` of the Sortkey is right at the end.

You could speed it up by helping the query use Zone Maps, which identify the range of values stored in each block.

If you know that the maximum sortkey is above a particular value, include that in the WHERE clause, eg:

```
SELECT MAX(sort_key) FROM tbl WHERE sort_key > 50000;
```

This will dramatically reduce the number of blocks that Redshift needs to retrieve from disk.